# Почему json загружается быстрее string в XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

Почему json загружается быстрее string в XMLHttpRequest?

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log("xml done");
};
xhttp.open("GET", "getObject", true);
xhttp.send();
```

---

Тестируемый объект размером 17 МБ

```
[
  {a:"some string"},
  {b:"some string"},
  ...
]
```

Если xhttp.responseType = 'json', то объект загружается за 0.3 секунды в среднем в браузер,
а если xhttp.responseType = '' (как строка), то 1.6-3 секунды

---

Сервер node + express

```
app.get("/getObject", function(req, res){
  res.send(big_data);
});
```

Почему так?

Comment: если я правильно  понимаю, то здесь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0 - говорится об обратном

Comment: Посмотрел видео, у меня с точностью наоборот ситуация

Comment: Мб браузер кешировал json?

Comment: Закешированные объекты и строки за 160 мс браузер вытаскивает из памяти.  А вообще я использую ещё xhttp.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

Comment: возможно, json сжимается (убирает лишние пробелы) перед отправкой, в отличии от строки? Или размер данных в обоих случаях одинаковый?

Comment: я бы проверил JSON.stringify() на данном объекте, возможно нашлась бы дельта по времени. так или иначе сервер шлет байты, ни строки, ни объекты

Answer (score 1):

Возможно из-за того, что на сервере у тебя отправляется `json`. Когда ты устанавливаешь в заголовке тип ответа `json`, тебе просто возвращается `json`, а когда указываешь `text`, то дополнительно вызывается функция `JSON.stringify(obj)`. Учитывая, размеры `json` объекта, предполагаю, что вызов функции `JSON.stringify(obj)` занимает дополнительное время.